# Dynamic tableview cell, prevent auto height constraint from being created

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, dynamic, constraints

I have been with this problem for a few days already and still haven't found a fix. Basically I am trying to create a `UITableView` with self sizing cells. I have set up the height of the cells being Automatic with `UITableViewAutomaticDimension`. The cell has a height constrained to test out my code since this constraint should determine the height of the cell. Here are my constraints for the cell:

```
let views = ["view": view]
self.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(
    withVisualFormat: "H:|[view]|",
    options: [],
    metrics: nil,
    views: views
))

self.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(
    withVisualFormat: "V:|[view]|",
    options: [],
    metrics: nil,
    views: views
))

NSLayoutConstraint(item: contentView, attribute: .width, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self.superview!, attribute: .width, multiplier: 1, constant: 0).isActive = true
```

And here is the error message I get:

```
2017-04-17 22:40:01.596805-0300 ViraVira-Info[52208:1001696] [LayoutConstraints] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
    (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x600000099190 h=--& v=--& UITableViewCellContentView:0x7f987070f5f0.height == 44.5   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000000966c0 UIView:0x7f9870709be0.height == 100   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600000098dd0 V:|-(0)-[UIView:0x7f9870709be0]   (active, names: '|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x7f987070f5f0 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600000098e70 V:[UIView:0x7f9870709be0]-(0)-|   (active, names: '|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x7f987070f5f0 )>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000000966c0 UIView:0x7f9870709be0.height == 100   (active)>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
```

As you can see the `tableview` creates automatically a `height constraint` which conflicts with my other height constraint.

```
"<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x600000099190 h=--& v=--& UITableViewCellContentView:0x7f987070f5f0.height == 44.5   (active)>"
```

But I can not find a way to delete or prevent this constraint from happening. I have already tried to set the `translatesAutoresizingMask` to false for the content view, the cell view it self and the `UIView` that's being added to the content view, but without success. Doing so gave me the following error:

```
Warning once only: Detected a case where constraints ambiguously suggest a height of zero for a `tableview cell's` content view. We're considering the collapse unintentional and using standard height instead.
```

Please ask for any additional information and I'll happily add it to this question.

Comment: view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
should help @J.Paravicini

Comment: Have you red the question? I stated that i've already tried so but without success :/

Comment: try it on cell.contentView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints

Comment: @J.Paravicini there have any other view if so set all view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

Comment: @NazmulHasan I tried setting the translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints in all views and subviews off and I've got the following error in the console: Warning once only: Detected a case where constraints ambiguously suggest a height of zero for a tableview cell's content view. We're considering the collapse unintentional and using standard height instead.

Comment: @J.Paravicini Forcing a return height and estimated height made tableview row

Comment: @J.Paravicini have you set for example
`self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 80`
`self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension`
in viewdidLoad()?

Comment: @J.Paravicini update my answer could you check that please

Answer (score 0):

**THIS IS ALL YOU NEED TO DO-:**

> MARK-: But I did it programatically.This works perfect.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController,UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource {

   lazy var tableView : UITableView = {
        var tableView  =  UITableView()
        tableView.delegate = self // Table view delegate
        tableView.dataSource = self // table view datasource
        tableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false // set  translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints to false
        return tableView 
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.addSubview(tableView) // Add table on view
        tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 50 // table row estimated row height
        tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension //Automatic dimensions

        tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell") // register cell
        view.addConstraintsWithFormat(format: "H:|[v0]|", views: tableView) // give table view constraints horizontal
        view.addConstraintsWithFormat(format: "V:|[v0]|", views: tableView) // vertical

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


    // MARK-: Table view DELEGATE METHODS

      func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
      {
        return 5
    }


    // Row display. Implementers should *always* try to reuse cells by setting each cell's reuseIdentifier and querying for available reusable cells with dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:
    // Cell gets various attributes set automatically based on table (separators) and data source (accessory views, editing controls)


    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
    {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel?.text = "abcd"
        cell.textLabel?.numberOfLines = 0 // SET YOUR LABEL numberOfLines to 0
        cell.textLabel?.sizeToFit()
        if indexPath.row == 1
        {
            cell.textLabel?.text = "asdvhvcjkhsvcjhsvcjhsvchjvcjhsvcjhsvchdveiuvcjsdvccjgdcgygdchjsvcjsvcjvclsvccvsjvhjsvchsvcvhdchvsjvhcjjhhyuioplkjhxxzasdfghtyuiklopl"
        }
        return cell
    }


     func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat
     {
        return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
     }


}
extension UIView
{

    func addConstraintsWithFormat(format:String,views:UIView...)
    {
        var allViews = [String:UIView]()
        for data in 0...views.count-1
        {
            let key = "v\(data)"
            allViews[key] = views[data]
        }
        addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: format, options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(), metrics: nil, views: allViews))

    }



}
```

To work with storyboard do this-:

[image]

The coding part-:

**ViewController-:**

```
class ViewController: UIViewController,UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet weak var dynamicTable: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        dynamicTable.estimatedRowHeight = 70 // table row estimated row height
       dynamicTable.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension //Automatic dimensions

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


    // MARK-: Table view DELEGATE METHODS

      func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
      {
        return 5
    }


    // Row display. Implementers should *always* try to reuse cells by setting each cell's reuseIdentifier and querying for available reusable cells with dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:
    // Cell gets various attributes set automatically based on table (separators) and data source (accessory views, editing controls)


    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
    {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! testing
        cell.automaticLabel?.text = "abcd"
        cell.automaticLabel?.numberOfLines = 0 // SET YOUR LABEL numberOfLines to 0
        cell.automaticLabel?.sizeToFit()
        if indexPath.row == 1
        {
            cell.automaticLabel?.text = "asdvhvcjkhsvcjhsvcjhsvchjvcjhsvcjhsvchdveiuvcjsdvccjgdcgygdchjsvcjsvcjvclsvccvsjvhjsvchsvcvhdchvsjvhcjjhhyuioplkjhxxzasdfghtyuiklopl"
        }
        return cell
    }


     func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat
     {
        return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
     }
```

**Custom cell Class-:**

```
import UIKit

class testing: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var automaticLabel: UILabel!
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }

}
```

Comment: An answer that only has code is not very helpful. Please explain _why_ this is what needs to be done. How did this code solve the problem in the question?